# Save User Info protected

Tags: xamarin, save, .net-standard

if I use Xam.Plugins.Settings to save, for example, token оr anything else, what level of security does this give me? Can I expect a greater level of security if I create my own Settings service in each platform project, which simply uses the default Api?

How and where do you store data such as a token and userName? Whether you use encryption or some paid plug-ins? I've heard a little about them in Unity, but I'd like to know more.

Comment: You can review `Xamarin.Essentials`: `Secure Storage` to see if it provides the level of security that you need (Note: all Mobile OS App security is NOT created the same and thus reviewing what Xamarin has implemented would be a wise move...just saying...) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Settings Plugin saves specific properties directly to each platforms native settings APIs (NSUserDefaults, SharedPreferences).

For example, in Android, the SharedPreferences are a file that is stored on the device filesystem, within the app's data directory, set with permissions that only the specific application can read/write. However, as everything, it can be "hacked", if you have root privileges, and try to access the filesystem, you can always see what's in the file.

What you can do, is to encrypt the data you save in the Properties, so you add an extra layer of security.